# If $P = NP \cap coNP$, can $P \ne NP$?

Tags: np-complete

In Scott Aaronson's *Quantum Computing since Democritus* he writes on page 65:

> Indeed, for all we know, it could be the case that $P = NP \cap coNP$ but still $P \ne NP$.

The same statement is in the lecture notes here:

http://www.scottaaronson.com/democritus/lec6.html

I was surprised to read that, until I realized he's talking about $NP$ but not necessarily $NP$-complete problems. So if I understand correctly, if $P = NP \cap coNP$ **and** $NP \cap coNP$ contains *any* NP-complete problems, then it is **not** possible that $P \ne NP$. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, your last statement is correct.

Comment: Alright, I posted a more detailed version as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last statement is correct.

If $\mathrm{NP} \cap \mathrm{coNP}$ contains a $\mathrm{NP}$-complete problem, then so does $\mathrm{P}$, which implies that $\mathrm{P} = \mathrm{NP}$.

Currently, it's suspected that $\mathrm{NP} \cap \mathrm{coNP}$ is properly contained in $\mathrm{NP}$, which implies that it does *not* contain any $\mathrm{NP}$-complete problems.  However, this has not been proved.  If it were, in particular it would imply that $\mathrm{P} \not= \mathrm{NP}$.

Comment: Whew, I'm glad you made that edit! :-)

Comment: Yeah, that was a pretty bad typo...